# How to avoid locking on Insert into..Select

Tags: mysql, locking

I wrote some SQL queries to do ETL processing which heavily uses INSERT INTO ... SELECT type queries. I see Mysql replication stops frequently due to locking issue. I tried setting up almost all possible TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVELs (READ UNCOMMITTED, COMMITTED) but none of them seems prevent to work. what are the possible ways to avoid this locking issue?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL always puts a shared lock on the rows you read from when you do "hybrid" statements that both read and write.

```
INSERT INTO <table> SELECT ...
CREATE TABLE <table> AS SELECT ...
SET @variable = (SELECT ...)
```

The only workaround is to do the operation in two steps:

1. Fetch rows to your client app using a read-only SELECT statement
2. Use the fetched data in a subsequent separate INSERT statement

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: Thanks Bill, Unfortunately, there is no application layer involved in my case. It is directly being executed on mysql using mysql command line.

Comment: Then the locking behavior I mentioned is unavoidable. Unless you feel like learning how to write python or javascript code in [mysql shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB:

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 READ;
... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

MyISAM:

```
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 READ;
... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: I do not think it will solve the issue. It will lock the table T2, so no other process can write to that and lock is help for longer, replication will fail with time out as it can not write to table T2

Comment: @Mkp, I can't see why replication will fail with timeout for not being able to write to t2, whereas replication is supposed to read from a primary to write to a replica. Replication is more likely to fail with timeout in case it *can't* read from t2, if t2 is replicated to another server.

Answer (score 0):

@Mkp, can you explicit what the error message was when replication stopped for "lock-related issues"? read-timeout of the source table, because of the write lock set by that statement?

Instead of bouncing to an app and back to the data layer, as suggested by @Bill Karwin, may I still suggest a 2-step scenario, 1st is to create a temporary table (possibly in memory too, if possible), by creating it and filling it in the same statement, then, step 2, is to copy from that tmp table to the final table.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is not your queries that deadlock on the MASTER, and it is only a replication problem, then you could use the [Row-Based replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html#replication-sbr-rbr-rbr-advantages). As only resulting data modification is transferred to the SLAVES and not the queries, you should not encounter locking issues.